# Lebesgue-Integrability of $x \mapsto \frac{\sin x}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

When we have the function $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and we want to check it ass for the integrability do we have to do the following to see if it is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$? $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}| \frac{\sin x}{x}|\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} dx=\mu (\mathbb{R})$$ is it correct so far?? How do we continue??

Comment: This is formally correct but is also an empty statement as the right hand side is $+\infty$.

Comment: Hiow can we check then if it is in L1 @GiuseppeNegro ?

Comment: You may want to check again the definition of $L^1$-space:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces

Comment: Do we not have to sow that the integral of the absolute value is finite?? @GiovanniDeGaetano

Comment: @MaryStar This is correct, but, as Giuseppe pointed out, this is not equivalent to show what you wrote in the question. Do you see what is the behavior of your function making it (or not) integrable?

Comment: I got stuck right now... What is the behaviour of the function?? @GiovanniDeGaetano

Comment: @Marystar Did you find the answer useful? If so please reward the time I invested thinking of your problem, and help to keep the website clean, by accepting the answer. Otherwise please let me know how can I improve my answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

1) Prove the following inequality
$$ \int_\mathbb{R} \left| \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \right| dx \geq 2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2}{k \pi}. $$

To prove it observe that 
$$\int_\mathbb{R} \left| \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \right| dx = 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{|\sin(x)|}{x} dx = 2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_0^\pi \frac{|\sin(x+k\pi)|}{x+k\pi} dx.$$

2) Examine the behavior of the series.

Comment: 1) How could I prove this inequality??

Comment: @Mary Star I edited the answer to extend the hint.

Comment: How could I use your answer to show that $f(x)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}{t}$ is not Lebesgue Integrable on (0,1)?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235812/show-improperly-riemman-integrable-function-is-not-lebesgue-integrable

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

1. Deduce from $$|\sin(x)| \geq \frac{1}{2} \qquad \text{for all} \, \, x \in \left[ \frac{1}{6}\pi, \frac{5}{6}\pi \right]$$ that $$|\sin(x)| \geq \frac{1}{2} \qquad \text{for all} \, \, x \in \left[ \frac{1}{6}\pi+ k \pi, \frac{5}{6}\pi +k \pi\right].$$
2. Show that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left| \frac{\sin x}{x} \right| \, dx \geq \int_{\{x \geq 0; |\sin(x)| \geq \frac{1}{2}\}} \frac{|\sin(x)|}{x} \, dx \geq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} \int_{\frac{1}{6}\pi+ k \pi}^{\frac{5}{6}\pi + k \pi} \frac{1}{x} \, dx.$$
3. Conclude from $$ \int_{\frac{1}{6}\pi+ k \pi}^{\frac{5}{6}\pi + k \pi} \frac{1}{x} \, dx \geq \frac{1}{\frac{5}{6} \pi + k \pi} \int_{\frac{1}{6}\pi+ k \pi}^{\frac{5}{6}\pi + k \pi} \, dx$$ and step 2 that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \left| \frac{\sin x}{x} \right| \, dx \geq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{5+6k}=\infty.$$