# Show improperly Riemann integrable function is not Lebesgue integrable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $$f(x)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}{t}.$$

Show that $\int^1_0 f(x)\,dx$ exists but $f\notin L^1$, i.e., on $(0,1)$ $f$ is  improperly Riemann integrable but not Lebesgue integrable.

**Attempt:**

Affirmation: $\int^1_0 f(x)\,dx$ exists (I am not very sure how to prove this either).

Now, using the following

> **Theorem**: $f\in L^1 \iff |f| = f^+ + f^- \in L^1$

I can reduce the proof that $f\notin L^1$ by showing that either $\int^1 _0 f^+\,d\lambda = \infty$ or $\int^1 _0 f^-\,d\lambda = \infty$, but I haven't been able to show this either.

Comment: Important distinction: you want to say that this $f$ is *improperly* Riemann integrable and not Lebesgue integrable. To see that, try taking the substitution $u=1/x$ to make an integral over $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: @Ian thanks, I'll correct that, this is left for excercise in (Grabinsky, "Teoría de la Medida") and used later as an example, so I asume it can be shown

Comment: You should probably change the title as well.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern is this right?

Comment: It is improperly Lebesgue integrable (for the same reason that it is improperly Riemann integrable).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Please read **carefully** what I wrote.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I've never seen a definition of "improperly Lebesgue integrable", but I expect it's like the definition of "improperly Riemann integrable", that is, the function is integrable over proper subintervals, and the limit of these integrals as the bounds of the subintervals tend to the bounds of the interval exists.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Why do you assert that this improperly Lebesgue integrable function is not improperly Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: These comments start to bother me. If you claim that such a function is improperly Lebesgue integrable, please tell me, what is $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|\,dx $$ or $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\lim_{M\to +\infty}\int_{\varepsilon}^{M}\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|\,dx  $$ if not $+\infty$ ?

Comment: It's not clear what "improperly Lebesgue integrable" should even mean, but it is true that for every $\delta>0$, $\int_{\delta}^1 \sin(1/x)/x dx$ exists as a Lebesgue integral and that the limit as $\delta \to 0^+$ of that exists.

Comment: Ian is on the money: $\int_\delta^1 \sin(1/t)\,dt/t$ exists **as a Lebesgue integral** and it tends to a limit, as $\delta\to0^+$. Therefore the **improper** Lebesgue integral $\int_0^1\sin(1/t)\,dt/t$ exists. Is this clear enough. Mr D'Aurizo, is "improper Lebesgue integrability" simply a synonym for "Lebesgue integrability" to you? If so, then why bother with the concept, or the name?

Comment: @Alfredo Lozano Does this help?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67198/does-int-0-infty-frac-sin-xxdx-have-an-improper-riemann-integral-or

Comment: Gentlemen, you can't fight in here!  This is the War Room.

Comment: Also see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948873)